# Python Multiplication list

Tags: python

why won't it return the answer?

```
    x=[1,2,3] 
    y=[2,4,6] 
    xy  = []  
    def mult_list(xy):      
        for i in range(0, len(x)):      
        xy.append(x[i]*y[i])      
        return xy
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected? You probably shouldn't be modifying the global list if that is in fact what you are doing. Else it will only work once :)

Comment: Well, for starters, your specification requires that the function take two lists as arguments, but you are only providing *one argument*. Furthermore, you are using globally defined lists... What's the calling code? You seem to fundamentally understand how function arguments are used.

Comment: your funciton must have 2 arguments. One for each list. And don´t define the list your are gonna return globally. do it inside your function and just return it

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your indentation is correct. `return xy` should be outside of the loop.
2. It is preferable not to have `xy` a global list. Instead, define it inside the function. If it is global you will get funny results if `mul_list` is called more than once.

```
def mult_list(list_a, list_b): 
    xy  = []      
    for i in range(0, len(list_a)):      
        xy.append(list_a[i] * list_b[i])      
    return xy

x = [1, 2, 3] 
y = [2, 4, 6]

print(mult_list(x, y))
#  [2, 8, 18]
```

But it is considered not pythonic to use `range` in order to index into a list. Instead you can use `zip`:

```
def mult_list(list_a, list_b): 
    xy  = []      
    for num_a, num_b in zip(list_a, list_b):      
        xy.append(num_a * num_b)      
    return xy

x = [1, 2, 3] 
y = [2, 4, 6]

print(mult_list(x, y))
#  [2, 8, 18]
```

Comment: it should be def mult_list(x,y):

Comment: (y) FYI I am not the one who down voted your answer :) I am the one who  up voted it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[1,2,3] 
y=[2,4,6]
res=[i*j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

What I have done here is used zip function.The zip() function take iterables (can be zero or more), makes iterator that aggregates elements based on the iterables passed, and returns an iterator of tuples.

example:

```
numberList = [1, 2, 3]
strList = ['one', 'two', 'three']

# No iterables are passed
result = zip()

# Converting itertor to list
resultList = list(result)
print(resultList)

# Two iterables are passed
result = zip(numberList, strList)

# Converting itertor to set
resultSet = set(result)
print(resultSet)
```

output:
`[]`
`{(2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (1, 'one')}`

Comment: You should provide some explanation instead of only throwing the answer at OP